# Using Groovy, how can we call a python script, in windows, with one argument

Tags: groovy

I need to run a python script in windows system using groovy script.

Example:

python.exe c:/main.py argument1

I am new to groovy and I don't know, how to do it.
Please share me groovy syntax to run python as mentioned in the above example

I am preparing this script for jenkins.

Comment: Use normal command execute like `"python c:/script.py".execute()`

Comment: @Bhanuchander_U,Thanks for your response, I have a file called test.groovy and I am executing it from windows machine cmd prompt. Example: groovy test.groovy, but it outputs nothing. In my groovy script, I have only one line called "python c:/main.py".execute(). but it didn't works, please help.

Comment: if you run that.. no output will print unless you print it as said in below answer by @rdmueller. you need to print the output if you need.... or you can redirect it to a out file like `"python file.py > output.txt".execute()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so, `"command".execute()` is the right start. 
But this command only starts a thread and you don't wait for the result.

try this code:

```
def task = "python main.py".execute()
task.waitFor()
println task.text
```

These lines start the execution, wait for it to finish and print the result.

To output already during execution for longer running tasks, I've written myself a small helper:

```
      String.metaClass.executeCmd = { silent ->
        //make sure that all paramters are interpreted through the cmd-shell
        //TODO: make this also work with *nix
        def p = "cmd /c ${delegate.value}".execute()
        def result = [std: '', err: '']
        def ready = false
        Thread.start {
            def reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.in))
            def line = ""
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (silent != false) {
                    println "" + line
                }
                result.std += line + "\n"
            }
            ready = true
            reader.close()
        }
        p.waitForOrKill(30000)
        def error = p.err.text

        if (error.isEmpty()) {
            return result
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("\n" + error)
        }
    }
```

This defines through meta programming a new method on `String` called `executeCmd`.

Put this on top of your file and then your line

```
"python c:/main.py".executeCmd()
```

This should show you all output *during* execution and it will help you to handle the paramaters the correcct way through the `"cmd /c"`-prefix. (If you just call execute on a string, you often run into problems with spaces and other characters in your command.

If you already have the parameters as a list and need some code which also runs on a *nix machine, try to call `execute()` on a list:

```
["python", "c:/main.py"].execute()
```

hope this helps

ps: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-executing-string-or.html

Comment: Thanks for you response, your solution works for me, I just used the three lines which you provided. def task = "python main.py".execute()
task.waitFor()
println task.text